# Angular 4 interceptor is not setting headers

Tags: angular

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
if (!jwt) {
  req = req.clone(
    {
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt)
    });
}
console.log(req);
return next
  .handle(req)
  .do(evt => {
    if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return Observable.throw(err);
  });
```

}

this is my intrceptor class,
in chrome request looks like this:
[chrome screenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRPMV.png)

CURL looks like this (copied from chrome devtools):

```
curl "http://192.168.10.220:8090/api/portal/getMojeRezerwacjeList" -X 
OPTIONS 
-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" 
-H "Origin: http://localhost:4200" 
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" 
-H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization" --compressed
```

there is clearly no header with Bearer and jwt token and 
I get 401 error all the time

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(!jwt)` instead of !!

Comment: it should, but the error is still there

Comment: I don't believe Angular 2 supports interceptors. Angular 4 does

Comment: corrected. Its angular 4

Comment: Is your `console.log` statement being printed?

Comment: @user184994 https://i.imgur.com/6vLirAq.png console print

Answer (score 0):

Try setHeaders instead of headers

const newRequest = req.clone({
              setHeaders: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token}